# How to get short-lived session_key based on REST API?

Tags: session, facebook-rest-api

I want to  find a way to let the session_key based on REST API expire to test my desktop app. How can I make an session_key based on REST API expired in short time? How can I get a short-lived session_key based on REST API?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The deprecated REST API endpoints which accepted a session key were all updated to use access tokens. There should be no need to use session_key anywhere in your code - thus the current Authentication documentation should be correct: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/